# Javascript + Vue: array failing to be reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following code in a .vue file:

```
<template>
  <button @click="entries.push(3)">
    Press me!
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="entry in entries" :key="entry">
      {{ entry }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script setup>
const entries = [1, 2]
</script>
```

After pressing the button I would expect a third `li` element to show up, yet nothing happens. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: const entries = ref([1,2]); use ref will fix your issue  https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a sandbox with the fix: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-pond-8jg5zw?file=/src/App.vuee

```js
<template>
  <button @click="entries.push(3)">Press me!</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="entry in entries" :key="entry">
      {{ entry }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const entries = ref([1, 2]);
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Use the `import { ref } from "vue";`

Tip: Be aware of the difference between `Ref` and `Reactive`

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref